# Keyboard Slow on a high power machine. 

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I am having a terrible time with my high powered machine. The keyboard is not displaying the keys as quickly as I type.  Sometimes I have to wait up to a minute for the key to display.  When I type ahead it sometimes loses characters.

I am not sure where to start looking for this problem.  It started about a month ago and I still have not figured out why.  It does not always do it.  But acts up about 2-3 minutes out of ever hour of use or thereabout.

How can I look to isolate and find the problem, and solve it?

Comment: Have you tried a different known working/older keyboard yet?  Tried a different USB port (if it's a USB keyboard)?

Comment: I'd look at the CPU temperature. And I'd try another keyboard.

Comment: Have you checked Task Manager for busy processes when it starts acting up?